# Resizing a div with an SVG image with CSS transition causes weird crosslines in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

For a website I wrote a short splash screen to hide the page until everything is loaded. The overlaying div then gets a new class and resizes/transforms to a smaller size and position.

The live example on https://www.hafen17.de/ shows the "problem" of the SVG: while resizing Firefox shows a cross in the back of the image.

I tried to reproduce this on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ujLf5d/5/) but there are no crosslines in the background.

HTML

```
<div id="loading"><img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    background-color: #cecece;
}
#loading {
    background-color: #25323f;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    -o-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all .8s ease;
}
#loading.close {
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
#loading img {
    max-width: 420px;
    height: auto;
    width: 60vw;
}
```

[Link to GIf preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU0Ux.gif)

Comment: Works for me on hafen24 with ff, no crosslines.

Comment: Hey @Harald, I fixed it by changing the class name which was already set by another plugin/css part.

Answer (score 0):

You see the result of these rules on your website (vendor prefixes shortened):

```
.close::after {
 transform:rotate(-45deg)
}
.close::before,.close::after {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 height:2px;
 width:100%;
 top:50%;
 left:0;
 margin-top:-1px;
 background:#000;
 opacity:.5;
 transition:opacity 0.3s ease-out
}
.close:hover::before,.close:hover::after {
 opacity:1
}
.close::before {
 transform:rotate(45deg)
}
```

Could it be you are using a class name for multiple purposes? There are more rules immediately before these with selectors `close.thick` and `.close.rounded`.

Comment: Ah, I think you are right. A plugin adds code for the class "close". 
The second answer already fixes it - will change the class to something more unique. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this styles to fix your problem:

```
#loading::before, #loading::after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: No idea why this helps but it does. Do you have an explanation for this strange behaviour? Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Sure. You are using the class name `.close` that already has some styles in your project. So I just remove this styles for exact your element.

Comment: Thanks again. I didnt check the double usage of the class name. My bad. Changed it to something unique.